# Confused by definition of an open set in "All the Mathematics You Missed"

Tags: general-topology, definition

On page 66 of Thomas Garrity's "All the Mathematics You Missed", Garrity gives the following definition of an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

> A set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ will be open if given any $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, there is a real number $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\{x : |x-a| < \varepsilon\}$ is contained in $U$.

This looks similar to the other definitions that I've seen that give the open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the open balls of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The part that throws me is "if given any a...". The way the definition is worded, it looks like he is saying that given any open set $U$ and any point $a$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is an open ball around $a$ contained in $U$. But that doesn't align with how open sets are usually defined, and it certainly doesn't look useful.

I guess my question comes down to this: am I misreading the definition, is the definition worded sloppily, or is something else going on here?

Comment: If you didn't make a mistake copying, the mistake is in the book. It ought to be "given any $a\in U$".

Comment: That's what I thought, but I am not nearly confident enough of a reader to say "that's wrong". Thanks.

Comment: I concur,$a$ must be in $U$, not arbitrarily in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, tiny typos. can have a huge impact on meaning. Time for errata.com :-).

Comment: I think this is a typo. Not a very bad one, anyway, I've seen worse. "if a point belongs to U, its neighbourhood does too" is approximately the meaning of the definition. But, certainly, you'll have to replace $R^n$ by $U$ in "...any point $a$ in $R^n$..."

Comment: P.S.: (off topic) check the definition of an open set in "Topology without tears" (free online), you'll get your mind blown! :)
A very different story.